# Calculating BIC for a HMM without any training data

Tags: hidden-markov-model, bic, likelihood

I need to evaluate my HMM models, that are trained using EM algorithm, since I don't have any training data. In order to evaluate with BIC or with most of the other criterions I need the log likelihood. But it seems it's too expensive to calculate.

In equations, I need 
$P(Z\vert\theta) = \sum_{X} P(X,Z \vert \theta) $

Where $Z$ observed states, $X$ hidden states and $\theta$ are the parameters. 
This summation is not possible to calculate for reasonably long Markov chain. For a example , a model 2 states and 100 time steps, will have $2^{100}$ possibilities to sum up. How can I do this ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer at the end. After learning parameter values ($\theta$), we have $\alpha(i)=P(Z,x=i\vert \theta)$ from forward algorithm. Then we can obtain $P(Z\vert \theta)$ by summing only over $i$ which has $2^k$ states, we don't have to sum over all possible time sequences. Here $x=i$ corresponds to hidden state at last time step. $k$ is my number of states.